# Compile one DataFrame from a loop sequence of smaller DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, append

I am looping through a list of 103 FourSquare URLs to find "Coffee Shops."
I can create a DataFrame for each URL and print each DataFrame as I loop through the list (sample output at bottom).

I cannot figure out how to append the DataFrame for each URL into a single DataFrame as I loop through the list. My goal is to compile a single DataFrame from the DataFrames I am printing.

```
x = 0

while x < 103 :

    results = requests.get(URLs[x]).json()

    def get_category_type(row):
        try:
            categories_list = row['categories']
        except:
            categories_list = row['venue.categories']

        if len(categories_list) == 0:
            return None
        else:
            return categories_list[0]['name']

    venues = results['response']['groups'][0]['items']

    nearby_venues = json_normalize(venues) # flatten JSON

    # filter columns
    filtered_columns = ['venue.name', 'venue.categories', 'venue.location.lat', 'venue.location.lng']
    nearby_venues =nearby_venues.loc[:, filtered_columns]

    # filter the category for each row
    nearby_venues['venue.categories'] = nearby_venues.apply(get_category_type, axis=1)

    # clean columns
    nearby_venues.columns = [col.split(".")[-1] for col in nearby_venues.columns]

    dfven = nearby_venues.loc[nearby_venues['categories'] == 'Coffee Shop']

    print(x, '!!!', dfven, '\n')

    x = x + 1
```

Here is some output (I do get complete results):

```
0 !!!                  name   categories       lat        lng
5         Tim Hortons  Coffee Shop  43.80200 -79.198169
8  Tim Hortons / Esso  Coffee Shop  43.80166 -79.199133 

1 !!! Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name, categories, lat, lng]
Index: [] 

2 !!!            name   categories        lat        lng
5     Starbucks  Coffee Shop  43.770367 -79.186313
18  Tim Hortons  Coffee Shop  43.769591 -79.187081 

3 !!!             name   categories        lat        lng
0      Starbucks  Coffee Shop  43.770037 -79.221156
4  Country Style  Coffee Shop  43.773716 -79.207027
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if this is bad form or a breach of etiquette but I solved my problem and figured I should post. Perhaps making an effort to state the problem for StackOverflow helped me solve it?

First I learned how to ignore empty DataFrames:

```
dfven = nearby_venues.loc[nearby_venues['categories'] == 'Coffee Shop']

if dfven.empty == False :
```

Once I added this code my printed output was a clean series of identically formatted data frames so appending them into one data frame was easy. I created a data frame at the beginning of my code (merge = pd.DataFrame()) and then added this line where I was printing.

```
merge = merge.append(dfven)
```

Now my output is perfect.

Comment: It's more idiomatic to use `if not dfven.empty` than `if dfvenempty == False`.